# Django i18n cannot use translated text in a dict

Tags: django, django-i18n

I am unable to store the translated texts in a dict

```
class TestAPIView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        return Response({'msg': _("My error msg")})
```

The code above works. However when I tried to put the text into a dict.

```
msg = {
   123 : _("My error msg")
}

class TestAPIView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        return Response({'msg': msg[123]})
```

This doesn't translated the text. I have tried rerunning the makemessages and compilemessages, but it doesn't help.

Any help?

Comment: How did you import `_`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with [**`gettext_lazy(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy), not [<s>**`gettext(…)`**</s> <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy) to prevent translating the string "*prematurely*":

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

msg = {123: _('My error msg')}


class TestAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        return Response({'msg': msg[123]})
```